# link Click tracking does not work on Safari browser

Tags: javascript, safari

I have a basic html page which has links that point to different site. What I want to do is track the clicks. I am doing so by sending a 0 pixel image call on Click event of the link without returning false on click event.

The same works fine on all the browsers except Safari(on windows OS).

when a link is clicked using javascript I delay the redirect and send an image request over to the server and log the click on server side. I have tried increasing the delay but with no success... The trackers work gr8 on all the browsers except Safari which does not sent the request at all.

I dont know why but possibly its that safari waits for the complete js to be executed before making the request and after the whole js is executed it gets redirected....

=========================================================

```
<html>
  <head>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      function logEvent(){
    image = new Image(1,1);
    image.onLoad=function(){alert("Loaded");};
    image.onLoad=function(){alert("Error");};
    image.src='http://#path_to_logger_php#/log.php?'+Math.random(0, 1000) + '=' + Math.random(0, 1000);             
    pauseRedirect(500);
      }

      function pauseRedirect(millis){
    var date = new Date();
    var curDate = null;
    do {curDate = new Date();}
    while(curDate-date < millis);
      }
    </script>   
  </head>
  <body>        
    <a href="http://www.google.com" onclick="logEvent(); return true;">Site 1</a><br/>
    <a href="http://www.yahoo.com" onclick="logEvent(); return true;">Site 2</a><br/>
  </body>
</html>
```

=========================================================

Code works in chrome, firefox, ie and Opera. Does not work on Safari only..... any clues....

Comment: Are you waiting for the image to finish loading or doing something like `setTimeout()`? Can we see some code?

Comment: Thanks for freezing the users browser for 500 milliseconds. Emulating sleep in JS... no comment. PS: I also think that Safari waits till the JS finished before it does the request. You should change your code to an asynchronous AJAX request instead of the image thingadong (that is, in case your counter is on the same server).

Comment: code added... :) My counter php is on a different server and its required to be kept there.. **ANY** other suggestions....

Comment: I have tested on Safari 5.0.3 and Safari 4.0.5 on Windows OS and the clicks don't get tracked on both the versions...

Comment: What did you end up doing to solve this? Running into a very similar issue, although I'm not freezing the browser as it seems like that's just a waste.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue with all WebKit browsers. In all others you only need to do new Image().src = "url", and the browser will send the request even when navigating to a new page. WebKit will stop the request before it's sent when you navigate to a new page right after. Tried several hacks that inject the image to the document and even [force a re-paint](http://functionsource.com/post/dont-be-trigger-happy-how-to-not-trigger-layout) through img.clientHeight. I really don't want to use event.preventDefault, since that causes a lot of headaches when a link has target="_blank", form submit, etc. Ended up using a synchronous XmlHttpRequest for browsers supporting [Cross Origin Resource Sharing](http://www.w3.org/TR/cors/), since it will send the request to the server even though you don't get to read the response. A synchronous request has the unfortunate side-effect of locking the UI-thread while waiting for response, so if the server is slow the page/browser will lock up until it receives a response.

```
var supportsCrossOriginResourceSharing = (typeof XMLHttpRequest != "undefined" && "withCredentials" in new XMLHttpRequest());
function logEvent() {
    var trackUrl = 'http://#path_to_logger_php#/log.php?'+Math.random(0, 1000) + '=' + Math.random(0, 1000);
    if(supportsCrossOriginResourceSharing) {
        xhrTrack(trackUrl);
    } else {
        imgTrack(trackUrl);
    }
}

function xhrTrack(trackUrl) {
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.open("GET", trackUrl, false);
    xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if(xhr.readyState >= this.OPENED) xhr.abort();
    }
    try { xhr.send() } catch(e) {}
}

function imgTrack(trackUrl) {
    var trackImg = new Image(1,1);
    trackImg.src = trackUrl;
}
```